# Can not connect to SQL Server in a different Domain

Tags: sql-server, azure, active-directory, cross-domain, sql-server-2017

We have 2 domains. One is the hosting domain (for the sql+webservers)and the other is the user domain (laptops etc).

We are currently having issues connecting to the `SQL` servers in `SSMS` (SQL Server Management Studio).

## The overall gist of the setup:

1) Our laptop is **test.mydomain.internal**

2) Connects to our SQL server **sqlserver01.azure.internal**, this is on a different hosting domain and is running on this domain (azure.internal) managed service accounts. We have set up a trust between

3) We are then presented an **error**

> ### TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to sqlserver01.
>
> ---
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 0)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=0&LinkId=20476

## What I have noted so far:

- Looking further into this, it looks like an issue to do with the managed service accounts and the access they have?
- I have noted that if we swap back from azure.internal managed service accounts for mydomain.internal generic service accounts, it works again.
- Connections are allowed when you RDP into the server and connect to the `SQL` instance over SSMS locally, this then uses NTLM authentication.

Hopefully, someone can help me with this!

Comment: This *might* be a better fit for [Stack DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).  If you agree you can move by clicking: Close >> Off-topic because >> This question belongs on another site in the Stack exchange network >> Belongs on dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on ServerFault.com.